# Why can't I access the Backing Field on an auto implemented property from within an inherited class

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, class, inheritance

I have a class that exposes an auto implemented property `Enabled`

```
Public MustInherit Class TopLevel
    Protected Property Enabled() As Boolean
End Class
```

In an inhertited class I cannot access _Enabled

```
Public Class SubClass
    Inherits TopLevel

    Public Function Foo() As string
        If Not _Enabled Then Return Nothing '<- This fails
    End SUb
End Class
```

But If I had not use an auto implemented property and declared my own backing-field as follows this is accessible from the subclass:

```
Private _Enabled as Boolean
```

*---- EDIT ----
The abve line is incorrect - this is not possible, it was in fact `Protected` in the original code which allowed access from the sub class See @JonSkeet answer
 ---- EDIT ----*

Of course I can just access `Enabled` from the sub class to work around this but can someone explain why this is the behaviour?

Comment: "this is accessible from the subclass:" A private field being accessible from a subclass certainly sounds strange to me. In C# it wouldn't be possible. Not sure about VB.net, but I'd be surprised if it allowed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But If I had not use an auto implemented property and declared my own backing-field as follows this is accessible from the subclass:
>
> ```
> Private _Enabled as Boolean
> ```

No it wouldn't - private fields aren't accessible from derived classes - only *protected* ones are. (The exception to this being nested classes, which have access to their containing class's private members.)

From the [docs for the Private modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx059ey1.aspx):

> Specifies that one or more declared programming elements are accessible only from within their declaration context, including from within any contained types.

Personally I'd regard it as bad form to access the backing field of an automatically implemented property directly anyway - in C#, it's not even available, as it's given an unspeakable name (one which isn't valid in C# itself). If you want the value of the property from your derived class, why don't you just access it *as* a property? That would be the appropriate approach even if you weren't using automatically implemented properties - your fields *should* be private.

Comment: Yes - my mistake, the code I was upgrading had specified the backing field as protected not private as I had stated - thanks for the quick answer

Comment: The names are unspeakable in C#. Are you sure it's the same in VB.net?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Nope, not now I've looked at the docs :) Edited.

Comment: Instance variables (including backing variables) can't be inherited in C# if they are marked protected. It is recommended against using a leading underscore for backing variables. I avoid this by using a trailing underscore instead, adopting the Java convention.

Comment: @Suncat2000: That's not true at all. *All* variables are inherited in derived classes... and I don't see using a trailing underscore as "the Java convention" at all - I can't remember *ever* seeing that in Java, and I've seen plenty of other conventions...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I amend that to _shouldn't_. You can create protected instance variables named with a leading underscore, but you will find they cause all sorts of strange problems if you try to use derived classes. I don't remember the specifics after nearly a decade, but it was my experience of and troubleshooting the problems that led me to avoid using underscore as a prefix, _influenced by the Java coding conventions I was following at the time_. Just because you haven't seen the convention doesn't mean it wasn't real.

Comment: @Suncat2000: Without specifics, I'm not going to just take your word for it, I'm afraid. I've seen plenty of C# code using an underscore prefix. *Double* underscores would be a different matter - see section 2.4.2 of the C# 5 spec. As for Java: if you'd specified the Java coding conventions you were following at the time, that would have been a different matter. Unqualified, "the Java coding conventions" usually refers to the ones authored by Sun: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: @Suncat2000: It's not clear what you're amending to "shouldn't" though - the programmer doesn't get to control which variables are inherited. *All* fields are inherited in derived classes, whether they're accessible or not. See section 3.4.4 of the C# 5 spec.

Comment: I was sharing facts about a real-world problem and a way I resolved it, to help others avoid wasting time when they run into the same problem. The "shouldn't" refers to using protected variables named with underscore prefixes. I appreciate a different perspective, and thanks for that. My issue is you're splitting hairs with your personal opinions and then criticizing me for offering a practical, proven workaround to a real Microsoft problem; that's a poor way to help others.

Comment: @Suncat2000: I would say that without any details of this "real Microsoft problem" it could well be that your solution wasn't actually the most useful one. How is a user going to know whether they've "run into the same problem" when you can't say what that problem was? Given that I've seen plenty of code using underscores as a prefix with no difficulties, I don't think it's actually helpful at all, I'm afraid.

Comment: This is the problem my approach fixed: code that used an inherited protected instance variable named with an underscore prefix was unable to retrieve a correct value because something buried in Microsoft's code wouldn't access it properly.

Comment: @Suncat2000: Well I can very easily show code where doing exactly that works fine, so without any sort of demonstration, I'm currently going to conclude that something else was going wrong and you probably misdiagnosed it. Of course, if you can reproduce it now, that would be great - and worth adding as a new SO question.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you wouldn't be able to access a **Private** member from a subclass.. anyway, auto-implemented property do not generate a backing field that you can access (otherwise they would be exactly the same as normal user-defined properties)./